# Running test on app created with start.spring.io causes: Error creating bean with name 'webHandler'

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I got his error while running tests on application setuped with start.spring.io: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'webFluxWebSocketHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/WebFluxAutoConfiguration$EnableWebFluxConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'webFluxWebSocketHandlerAdapter' threw exception with message: jakarta/websocket/Endpoint

My `build.graddle` ( I think that the most important thing in this case):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.2'
    id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.23'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-docker-compose'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework:spring-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.graphql:spring-graphql-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
    testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:rabbitmq'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

`compose.yml`

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=mydatabase'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret'
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=myuser'
    ports:
      - '5432'
  rabbitmq:
    image: 'rabbitmq:latest'
    environment:
      - 'RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=secret'
      - 'RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=myuser'
    ports:
      - '5672'
```

Test running application:

```
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class TestTest2Application {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgresContainer() {
        return new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:latest");
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    RabbitMQContainer rabbitContainer() {
        return new RabbitMQContainer("rabbitmq:latest");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.from(Test2Application::main).with(TestTest2Application.class).run(args);
    }

}
```

Have anyone any idea why I got this error and how to fix it?